# Проблема с формированием роутов после подключения swagger

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger

Подключил в проект `swagger`. Обнаружил что он затягивает только те `action's`, в которых прописан роут. Пустой `[HttpGet]` или `[HttpGet()]` не катит.

Проблема в дефолтном роуте.

Т.е. можно так:

`http://domen.com/controller`

`http://domen.com/controller/index`

И будет одно и тоже, т. к. стоит роут:

```
       app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );
        });
```

И получается если я ставлю 2 роута, то `swagger` формирует 2 адреса `API` с одинаковой начинкой.

Пробовал прописывать так: `[HttpGet("Home/{Index?}")]` - но тогда `swagger` думаешь что `Index` - это параметр.

Как прописать роут, не потеряя обе ссылки? Ну и конешно чтобы `swagger` отобразил хорошо.

Comment: вот так не пробовали? [HttpGet, Route("Index")]

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov не пробовал, завтра попробую уже, спасибо за предложение ;) И наверное `[HttpGet, Route("IController/Index")]` ?

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov так не работает роут до контроллера (дефолтный `index` не забирает)

Answer (score 0):

сделал два похожих метода:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index() => this._Index();

    [HttpGet("DeviceRoute/Index")]
    public IActionResult _Index()
    {
        List<DeviceRouteViewModel> result = _deviceRouteManager.Value.GetChildsByParent(null)
        return View("Index",result);
    }
```

И теперь в swagger затягивает только второй. Но когда переходишь на роут, не записывая `action` выполняется первый метод